# FilterExpression only work in form

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, qgsexpression

I make a QGIS plugin for 3.10.
and use Relational value but my key is 2 thing.

1. a string
2. a int

So I use the key colonne as my int and add a filter expression to add key

`"TYPE_MAT" =  current_value('Type_mat')`

And in the form its work great but when i open all the data in attribute table
the 2nd filter doesn't work

so my "Value" is not the good value.

Its a a good int but the String value is the first value with this int doesn't matter of the string key

I need help or i will have to concatenate the 2 keys and it doesn't feel clean.